# iptables DNAT traffic to localhost weird behavior

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, netfilter

I hit a problem when trying to understand how iptables handles DNATed packet..
I run a server at localhost:8000, and I added a rule to nat table:

```
-A OUTPUT -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Then I added a rule to filter table:

```
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

When I run `curl 1.2.3.4`, it just hangs there and has no response - seems it is blocked by the DROP rule. After I added following rule to filter table:

```
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

The curl command can successfully return localhost:8000 server's content.

I'm really confused, as far as I understand, the `curl 1.2.3.4` command will firstly be handled by nat table, after DNAT, the packet's destination is changed to 127.0.0.1, which should be handled by lo interface, and shouldn't be blocked by `-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP` rule. One thing makes me more confused, I run `tcpdump -i eth0 host 127.0.0.1`, there is no output.

Could someone please help me understand what happened?

1. Why the DNATed traffic whose dst is localhost is blocked by a rule whose interface is `eth0`?
2. Why the tcpdump command gives no output?

Comment: Because iptables (`OUTPUT`) matches the traffics before they actually get out of their (original) outbound interface, which was determined by the corresponding route (`dev`)? And because the `DNAT` rule changes the destination address, the outbound interface will be "updated" accordingly (as per the routes) after it get past `OUTPUT`, so the traffics that got matched will not actually get past / reach `eth0` either (but is looped back, more or less), so `tcpdump` will not give any "out" logs for them. (Apparently you won't get any either even if you simply ping `127.0.0.1`.)

Comment: @TomYan many thanks for the explanation! It makes great sense. The key point here is the sequence: the packet which is originally handled by `eth0` need to firstly pass OUTPUT chain and then the outbound interface will be "updated" to `lo`(reroute happens here). I find the [processing flow chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg), which exactly matches what you said and can explain the question.